# Ignoring not void method inside testing method in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

In class Account I have a method `public Account reserveA()` which I want to test, inside `reserveA` is called a method `public Bank DAO.createB()`. Is there a way to call `reserveA()` in test method but ignore call `DAO.createB()`? Non of these methods are void.
I tried:

```
doNothing().when(Account).reserveA(param1, param2);
```

but it's not the proper way.

Comment: In test method, comment the line where the `createB()` function is executed

Comment: It seems you're asking how to use Mockito. Have you read its documentation? It's quite easy and pleasant to read. And you'll learn a lot of stuff. https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html. If you actually want an answer, then post code.

Comment: @javimovi `createB` is not even called in test method. Just `reserveA` is called and inside this `createB` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doNothing() is reserved only for void methods.
If your method returns something, then you are required to do as well (or throw exception).
Depending on complexity of your `Account.reserveString()`, you may need to mock some more than just this one method call if result is used somewhere else.

Trying to use `doNothing()` on non-void method results in error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Only void methods can doNothing()!
Example of correct use of doNothing():
    doNothing().
    doThrow(new RuntimeException())
    .when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Above means:
someVoidMethod() does nothing the 1st time but throws an exception the 2nd time is called
```

Consider such classes:

```
@Component
public class BankDao {
    public BankDao() {}

    public void createVoid() {
        System.out.println("sth - 1");
    }

    public String createString(){
        return "sth - 2";
    }
}

@Service
public class Account {
    @Autowired
    private final BankDao DAO;

    public Account(BankDao dao) {
        this.DAO = dao;
    }
    public void reserveVoid() {
        System.out.println("before");
        DAO.createVoid();
        System.out.println("after");
    }
    public void reserveString() {
        System.out.println(DAO.createString());
    }
}
```

For which Test class is made:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccountTest {
    @Mock
    private BankDao bankDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private Account account;

    @Test
    public void reserveVoid_mockBankDaoAndDontUseRealMethod() {
        doNothing().when(bankDao).createVoid();
        account.reserveVoid();
    }

    @Test
    public void reserveString_mockBankDaoAndDontUseRealMethod() {
        when(bankDao.createString()).thenReturn("nothing");
        account.reserveString();
    }
}
```

Running such a test will produce:

```
nothing
before
after
```

If you change @Mock to @Spy and remove lines with doNothing() and when(), then you'll be calling original methods. Result would be:

```
sth - 2
before
sth - 1
after
```

Comment: No need for @Autowired, Spring IoT already handles DI through private final